# Adjust DB structure to support filtering conversations and deleting them

Tags: mysql, sql, messaging

I have a GWT application, which has a conversation system integrated within. To this conversation system, I have the following DB structure.

```
create table if not exists conversation(
    id int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_one varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    user_two varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    subject varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    ip varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    date varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    filter varchar(20) DEFAULT 'Inbox'
);

create table if not exists conversation_reply(
    id int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    reply text,
    username varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    ip varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    date varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    conv_id_fk int(11) NOT NULL REFERENCES conversation(id)
);
```

I implemented a filtering mechanism where you can move conversation from Inbox to Archive or Important, or others. But when I execute the query which updates the filter:

```
update conversation set filter=? where id=?;
```

It will update this both to the user_one and user_two, since the GUI is the same to both users..there is no difference between user_one and user_two in terms of how the GUI looks like. So the select, which gets all conversations looks like this:

```
select * from conversation where (user_one=? or user_two=?) and filter=? order by id desc
```

How should I change the DB structure in order to make the operations above (moving and deleting) work properly, because as I said, when I move as user_one, it will move to user_two as well, deleting the conversation from one would delete it from the other too.

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simplest solution: add a 2nd filter field to the conversation table.

Answer (score 0):

The way to restructure your table is to move the user participants into a separate table, where you store two rows for two participants, and they're both in the same column.

```
create table if not exists conversation(
    id int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    subject varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    ip varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    date varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    filter varchar(20) DEFAULT 'Inbox'
);

create table if not exists participants(
    conversation_id int NOT NULL,
    user_id id NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (conversation_id, user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (conversation_id) REFERENCES conversation(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id)
);
```

Then you can use a multi-table update for all conversations involving a given user:

```
update participant p join conversation c on p.conversation_id = c.id
set c.filter=? 
where p.conversation_id=? and p.user_id=?;
```

This also prepares you for some future feature to allow multi-way conversations between three or more participants.